Why don't API-defined properties automatically get overrides on edit?
After linking an asset and making a library override, built-in properties (like parent) and Custom Properties (when "Library Overridable" has been checked) have overrides automatically set (UI turns teal) on edit, but API-defined properties do not. The API properties have override={'LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE'}, and I'm able to RMB > "Define Override", but editing those fields without explicitly clicking "Define Override" results in a transient change only which gets reverted when the .blend file is saved. In other cases, the linked object (not the override object) seems to receive the edit and all override objects then see that change.
Is this a bug? Is it by design? Have I mis-configured something?

Hello, could you elaborate on the last sentence of the first paragraph ? The original object in the linked file gets modified ? That shouldn't be possible. Cheers

Not the linked file, but the linked object in the current file. If you look in the Data API, the linked object (non-override object) has this api property change when a single override object exists. If multiple override objects exist, then the api property changes but it gets reset on save to the last value it had when a single object existed

Turns out this is a result of PropertyGroup subclasses needing an additional PointerProperty. The properties within the PropertyGroup were marked with override = {'LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE'}, but the PointerProperty also needs to be marked as such! Without it, the API properties in the property group behave very erratically. With it, they behave just like built-in properties w.r.t. library overrides.
The offending line: bpy.types.Object.propgroup = bpy.types.PointerProperty(type=MyPropGroup, override={'LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE'})
Edit: thanks to the blender dev who added this note to the docs!

Wow, nice find. I don't remember seeing this documented anywhere either. Cheers
